# Leads to HTTP ERROR 500 PHP and SQL and i can´t solve it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I m trying to show on a page `{"status":1}` but instead it gives an error 500. All my code it seems to be working on database and on the plataform.

It gives this errors on error log:

1. [error] 42094#0: *233568 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /var/www/.../.../.../.../classes/pageuser.class.php on line 519
2. PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /var/www/.../.../.../.../classes/loan.class.php on line 537" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162..., server: interno.neeec.pt, request: "GET /loans/tickets/pay HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web20.sock:", host: "interno.neeec.pt"

On pageuser.class.php:

```
 case "loans/tickets/pay":
            $this->template = "no_render";
            $response = null;
            if (Loan::payTicket($_POST["id"], $user->getID())) {
                $response = ["status" => 1];
            } else {
                $response = ["status" => 0, "err" => "Erro ao atualizar base de dados"];
            }
            die(json_encode($response));
            return;
```

On loan.class.php:

```
    public static function payTicket($ticket_id, $user_id)
{
    $ticket_value = Loan::getTicketValue($ticket_id);
    $database = new Database();
    $connection = $database->getConnection();
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE loan_tickets SET `paid`=1,date_of_payment=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $ticket_id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `c3interno`.`payment_methods` SET `expected_value` = `expected_value` + $ticket_value WHERE `id` = 6");
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `c3interno`.`payment_methods_logs` (`payment_method`,`type`,`value`,`user_id`,`date`,`reason`) VALUES (6,5,$ticket_value,$user_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'Delay')");
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: _"All my code is working"_ - clearly something isn't . Have you looked in the server error log?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: I don't know. Every system is different. On a Linux server it'll usually  be somewhere in /var/log/ but different linux flavours have different defaults, and your Apache  configuration may have it somewhere different again. For Windows it will depend on how you've configured IIS. For hosted systems you might not have access to the raw file, but a copy will be placed in your user area somewhere. Frankly, as a developer, this is something you should already know for your systems.

Comment: i acessed it by ftp the error log

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Is this a production site processing actual payments? You have **serious security issues** in this code.

Comment:  I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. The style of coding used here is not sustainable,  it is extremely difficult to debug and maintain.

Comment: Should it be like this?

$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `c3interno`.`payment_methods` SET `expected_value` = `expected_value` + ? WHERE `id` = 6");
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $ticket_value);

Comment: This is a template that i am doing maintenance,so i cannot change it ,thanks anyways for the tip at laravel framework

Comment: it seems that my collumn value = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do some basic error checking.  The first warning and probably the root cause is that the $_POST variable "id" was not sent.  I have no idea why, you would need to investigate. If this is an optional variable, something like `if (isset($_POST["id"]))` should be used to see if it exists before trying to use it.

The second error occurs because `$stmt` is false due to `prepare()` returning a failure state.  See [about PDO return values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-returnvalues). You need to check for errors with something like `if ($stmt === false)`.

Comment: Yes it doesn t exist wtf,but why? hmm

Comment: Checking with `=== false` is unnecessary. `if (!$stmt)` is sufficient.

Comment: Thankss tadman the problem was interpolation between php and sql